# JavaScript Regex - Splitting a string into an array by the Regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Given an input field, I'm trying to use a regex to find all the URLs in the text fields and make them  links. I want all the information to be retained, however.

So for example, I have an input of "http://google.com hello this is my content" -> I want to split that by the white space AFTER this regex pattern from another stack overflow question (regexp = /(ftp|http|https)://(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(/|/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!-/]))?/) so that I end up with an array of ['http://google.com', 'hello this is my content'].

Another ex: "hello this is my content http://yahoo.com testing testing http://google.com" -> arr of ['hello this is my content', 'http://yahoo.com', 'testing testing', 'http://google.com']

How can this be done? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `(ftp|http|https)://\S+` is enough to get the url part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First transform all the groups in your regular expression into non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`) and then wrap the whole regular expression inside a group, then use it to split the string like this:

```
var regex = /((?:ftp|http|https):\/\/(?:\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(?:\S+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:.?+=&%@!-/]))?)/;
var result = str.split(regex);
```

**Example:**

```js
var str = "hello this is my content http://yahoo.com testing testing http://google.com";

var regex = /((?:ftp|http|https):\/\/(?:\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(?:\S+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:.?+=&%@!-/]))?)/;
var result = str.split(regex);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up customizing it after using the regex you provided. thank you for your help @ibrahimmahrir

Answer (score 1):

You had few unescaped backslashes in your `RegExp`.

```js
var str = "hello this is my content http://yahoo.com testing testing http://google.com";
var captured = str.match(/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!-/]))?/g);

var nonCaptured = [];
str.split(' ').map((v,i) => captured.indexOf(v) == -1 ? nonCaptured.push(v) : null);

console.log(nonCaptured, captured);
```

Comment: so this works for the url links i want but I also want to capture the non-regex content (i.e. "hello this is my content") into a separate array

Comment: forgot to tag you :) @kinduser

Comment: thanks! I ended up customizing it a bit after you provided me with the regex @kinduser